Proof check - find a domain $U$ and a continuous branch of the argument $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(U)=(0,\infty)$

Find a domain $U \subseteq \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} $ and continuous branch of the argument $\alpha: U \to \mathbb R$ such that $\alpha(U)=(0,\infty)$.

Denote $\textrm{Arg}: \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \to (-\pi,\pi]$ as the principle branch of the argument. We've defined a continuous branch of the argument as any continuous function $\alpha: U \to \mathbb R$ such that $U \subseteq \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is a domain (open and connected), and for all $z \in U$: $$\alpha(z) \in \{\textrm{Arg}(z)+2\pi k|k\in \mathbb Z\}$$
or equivalently $\alpha$ satisfies: $$e^{i\alpha(z)} = e^{i\textrm{Arg}(z)}$$ for all $z \in U$.
I would highly appreciate it if anyone could take a look at my attempt. Here it is:
Define $U=\mathbb C \setminus [0,\infty)$ - this is indeed open and connected, hence a domain, and $0 \notin U$. Define: $$\alpha(z) = \theta(z)+2\pi k(z)$$ where: $$\theta(z) = \textrm{Arg}(-z)+\pi$$ and $k(z)\in \mathbb Z$ such that: $$\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z|-\theta(z))<k(z)\le\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z|-\theta(z))+1$$
Then $\alpha$ is well defined as there exists exactly one integer value in $(\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z|-\theta(z)),\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z|-\theta(z))+1]$ for all $z\in U$.
We've seen in class that $\theta(z)$ is indeed a continuous branch of the argument in $U$, and so:
$$e^{i\alpha(z)}=e^{i(\theta(z)+2\pi k(z))}=e^{i\theta (z)}e^{2i\pi k(z)}=e^{i\textrm{Arg}(z)}$$ So $\alpha$ is indeed a branch of the argument.
We'll now show $\alpha$ is continuous. Let $z_0 \in U$. Observe that for any $z \in U$ we have:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z|-\theta(z))-\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z_0|-\theta(z_0))-1<k(z)-k(z_0)<\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z|-\theta(z))+1-\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z_0|-\theta(z_0))$$
The RHS converges to $1$ as $z \to z_0$ and the LHS converges to $-1$ as $z \to z_0$ (since $\theta(z)$ and $|z|$ are continuous), and so: $$ \lim_{z \to z_0} (k(z)-k(z_0))=0$$
But then:
$$|\alpha(z)-\alpha(z_0)|=|\textrm{Arg}(-z)-\textrm{Arg}(-z_0)+2\pi (k(z)-k(z_0)|\le $$
$$\le |\textrm{Arg}(-z)-\textrm{Arg}(z_0)|+2\pi |k(z)-k(z_0)| \underset{z\to z_0}{\to} 0$$
and so $\alpha$ is continuous.
Lastly, notice: $$k(z)>\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z|-\theta(z))>\frac{1}{2\pi}(|z|-2\pi)>-1$$
Hence $k(z) \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$, and so $\alpha(z) \in (0, \infty)$ for all $z\in U$. But this also implies that $k(z) \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$, and so, as a continuous function to $\mathbb R$, it obtains any value in $(0,\infty)$. Therefore $\alpha(U)=(0,\infty)$.
Thank you so much in advance!
